# Is the preimage of U in Euclidean topology?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $T_e$ be the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R} $ and let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be the function $f(x) =\begin{cases} 0 & , x< 0 \\ 1 &, x\geq 0\end{cases}$.

1. Does it hold $f^{-1}(U)\in T_e$ for all subsets $U\in T_e$? Is $f:(\mathbb{R}, T_e) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, T_e) $ continuous?
2. What is the most coarse topology $T$ on $\mathbb{R} $ such that $f:(\mathbb{R}, T) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, T_e)$ is continuous?

So for 1 we have to check if the preimage of an open subset is open, right? Byt how can we check that without knowing ifvthe function is continuous or not?

Comment: That's the problem. You are given the topology and you are asked if $f$ is continuous. Which value of $x$ do you think is the point of interest?

Comment: Is it the point $x=0$ ? @JohnDouma

Comment: That's right. Consider a small open interval around either $0$ or $1$ in the codomain. Is it open? What about its inverse?

Comment: Consider an open interval containing $1$ excluding $0$. Its inverse image is $x\ge0$ which is not open.

Comment: Ahh therefore the preimage of open subsets is not open, i.e it doesn't hold that $f^{-1}(U)\in T_e$ for all U and so f is not continuous. Is that correct? In part 2, we have to define the domain in that way so that we get continuity, or not? @ShubhamJohri

Comment: Since the preimage of open subsets is not always open, t doesn't hold that $f^{-1}(U)\in T_e$ for all U and so f is not continuous. Is that correct? In part 2, we have to define the domain in that way so that we get continuity, or not? @JohnDouma

Comment: Yes, that is right for part $1$. In part $2$, look for all possible inverse images of open sets in the codomain (think along the lines whether the open set contains $0$ or $1$ or both $0,1$ or none of them since the range contains just $0,1$). Does the set of all possible inverse images form a topology?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $U = (\frac12,\frac32)$ which is open in $T_e$.
Then $f^{-1}[U]= \{x \in \Bbb R\mid f(x) \in U\}=\{x\in \Bbb R\mid f(x)=1\}= [0,\rightarrow)$, which is *not* open (as $0$ is not an interior point).
Conclusion: $f$ is not continuous, as a map from $(\Bbb R,T_e)$ to itself.

For $2$, we need all posssible inverse images of open sets, i.e. $[0,\rightarrow)$ and $(\leftarrow,0)$ to be open( together with $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R$), these $4$ sets form a (very coarse) topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Why does it hold that $ \{x \in \Bbb R\mid f(x) \in U\}=\{x\in \Bbb R\mid f(x)=1\}$ although $1\notin  U$ ?

Comment: And also  $\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{3}$ so did you mean an other interval? So maybe an interval that contains $1$ is meant?

Comment: @MaryStar yes I edited.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

$f $ is not continuous rel $T_e $.  Just look at the graph.  The image of $\mathbb R $ is not connected.

For part two, there seem to be just two sets, $[0,\infty) , (-\infty,0) $, needed, besides  $\emptyset $ and $\mathbb R $.

Comment: Why do we get these intervals? How do we gwt a coarse topology?

Comment: The image is $\{0,1\}$.  There are only four possible inverse images.  And I have listed them.

Comment: If we remove any of the four sets, the function won't be continuous.  Thus it's the coarsest.  For instance, the function is not continuous if we put on the trivial topology.  $\{0,1\}$ is discrete, so we need all $4$.

Comment: The trivial topology is the one of the first question?

Comment: No, it's at the opposite extreme from the discrete topology.  It consists in just $\mathbb R$ and $\emptyset$.  I mentioned it because it's the coarsest.  But the function won't be continuous with it, as it is not with respect to the usual topology (first question).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! :-)